# Is there a way to use a PHP var as height and width in a CSS style?

Tags: php, css

I've been working on this for some time now but I can't get it to work. How can I set the vars to be the width and height of this `img`?

```php
for ($x = 1; $x <= $aantal; $x++) {
    echo "<img style= 'width: '$width'px; height: '.$height.'px;' src='Pics\helm.jpg'>";
}
```

Comment: `echo "<img style='width:{$width}px; height:{$height}px;' src='Pics\helm.jpg'>";`

Comment: omg @lagbox I love you thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is happening when you're inserting the **PHP** variables on the **echo content**.

You can solve it by adding `{` before the variable and `}` at the end:

`echo "<img style='width: {$width}px; height: {$height}px;' src='Pics\helm.jpg'>";`

Also, you can concatenate these strings:

`echo "<img style='width: " . $width . "px; height: " . $height . "px;' src='Pics\helm.jpg'>";`

You can read more about PHP **String Operators** [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).